# How can I load data from my JSON file to my HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

My goal is load data from my JSON to my HTML page.

---

## Approach

- I made a JS file : `update-info.js`
- In there, I made ajax call to my JSON file data.json
- If success, I use jQuery `.html()` function to update my HTML DOMs text fields.
- unfortunately, it only work on Chrome.

---

## Result in Chrome

[image]

---

## Result in Firefox + Safari

[image]

I’m not sure why does it do that.

Did I do anything that I’m not suppose to ?

Console Error :

> SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.

---

## JS

```
'use strict';

define(['jquery'], function($) {

  $(function() {

    var basePath = "/BIM/resources/js/reports/student/course-benchmark/";

    $.ajax({

      url: basePath + "data.json",
      type: "GET",
      dataType : "json",

      success: function( objects ) {

         // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
         google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
         google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart());

         function drawChart() {

           var options = {
            width: 160,
            height: 160,

            chartArea: {
              left: 10,
              top: 20,
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%"
            },


            colors: ['#F46E4E',  '#F9C262' , '#ADB55E',],
            legend: 'none',
            enableInteractivity: false,
            pieSliceText: 'none',

          };

          var data              = {};
          var chart             = {};

          var danger            = {};
          var warning           = {};
          var success           = {};
          var danger_list       = {};
          var warning_list      = {};
          var success_list      = {};

          var report_type       = {};
          var report_type_car   = {};
          var report_type_cdr   = {};
          var report_type_title = {};

          var section_num       = {};
          var assignment        = {};
          var date              = {};
          var correct_num       = {};
          var correct_total_num = {};
          var avg_score         = {};


          for (var object in objects) {


            danger[object]            = $('#pc-danger-'+ object);
            warning[object]           = $('#pc-warning-'+ object);
            success[object]           = $('#pc-success-'+ object);
            danger_list[object]       = $('#pc-danger-list-'+ object);
            warning_list[object]      = $('#pc-warning-list-'+ object);
            success_list[object]      = $('#pc-success-list-'+ object);

            report_type[object]       = $('#sa-report_type-'+ object);
            report_type_car[object]   = $('#sa-report-type-car-'+ object);
            report_type_cdr[object]   = $('#sa-report-type-cdr-'+ object);
            report_type_title[object] = $('#sa-report-type-title-'+ object);

            section_num[object]       = $('#sa-section-num-'+ object);
            assignment[object]        = $('#sa-assignment-'+ object);
            date[object]              = $('#sa-date-'+ object);
            correct_num[object]       = $('#sa-correct-num-'+ object);
            correct_total_num[object] = $('#sa-correct-total-num-'+ object);
            avg_score[object]         = $('#sa-avg-score-'+ object);




             function updateInfo(x) {

              danger[object].html(objects[x].danger);
              warning[object].html(objects[x].warning);
              success[object].html(objects[x].success);

              danger_list[object].html(objects[x].danger_list);
              warning_list[object].html(objects[x].warning_list);
              success_list[object].html(objects[x].success_list);

            }


            function updateStudentAccordion(x) {


              var report_type_full = objects[x].report_type.split(/(\s+)/);
              var car = report_type_full[0];
              var cdr = report_type_full[2];

              // console.log(cdr);

              report_type_car[object].html(car);
              report_type_cdr[object].html(cdr);

              report_type_title[object].html( car + " " + cdr + " " + objects[x].section_num );

              section_num[object].html(objects[x].section_num);
              assignment[object].html(objects[x].assignment);
              date[object].html(objects[x].date);
              correct_num[object].html(objects[x].correct_num);
              correct_total_num[object].html(objects[x].correct_total_num);
              avg_score[object].html(objects[x].avg_score);

            }

            var total = objects[object].danger + objects[object].warning + objects[object].success ;

            data[object] = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

              ['Piechart' , 'Number of Skills'],
              ['danger'   , ( objects[object].danger/total )  * 100  ],
              ['warning'  , ( objects[object].warning/total ) * 100  ],
              ['success'  , ( objects[object].success/total ) * 100  ],


              ]);

            // piechart object
            var $el = $('#sa-piechart-' + object  );

            // button
            var button = $('.sa-report-btn-'+ object );

            // append
            var $el = $('#sa-piechart-' + object ).length ? $('#sa-piechart-' + object ) : $('<div id="sa-piechart-' + object +'"></div>').appendTo($('#sa-piechart-'+ object ));


            chart[object] = new google.visualization.PieChart($el[0]);


            // Call Functions
            updateStudentAccordion(object);
            chart[object].draw(data[object], options );
            updateInfo(object);

          }

        }

      },

      error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );

        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
      },


    });

});

});
```

---

## JSON

```
{

    "a": {

        "report_type": "chapter test",
        "section_num": "2",
        "assignment": "algebra 1",
        "date": "2/10/2015",
        "correct_num": "15",
        "correct_total_num": "20",
        "avg_score": "89",
        "danger": "5",
        "danger_list": "5,10,15,19,23",
        "warning": "8",
        "warning_list": "3,7,11,13,14,16,21,22",
        "success": "12",
        "success_list": "1,2,4,6,8,9,12,17,18,20,24,25"
    },

    "b": {

        "report_type": "section exercise",
        "section_num": "2.2",
        "assignment": "algebra 2",
        "date": "2/09/2015",
        "correct_num": "11",
        "correct_total_num": "25",
        "avg_score": "44",
        "danger": "12",
        "danger_list": "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,3,4",
        "warning": "2",
        "warning_list": "1,2",
        "success": "11",
        "success_list": "21,21,23,24,25,5,6,7,8,9,10"
    },

    "c": {

        "report_type": "chapter test",
        "section_num": "1",
        "assignment": "algebra 3",
        "date": "1/10/2015",
        "correct_num": "15",
        "correct_total_num": "20",
        "avg_score": "75",
        "danger": "0",
        "danger_list": "",
        "warning": "10",
        "warning_list": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10",
        "success": "15",
        "success_list": "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25"
    },

    "d": {

        "report_type": "practice test",
        "section_num": "1",
        "assignment": "algebra 4",
        "date": "1/09/2015",
        "correct_num": "15",
        "correct_total_num": "20",
        "avg_score": "79",
        "danger": "5",
        "danger_list": "1,2,3,4,5",
        "warning": "0",
        "warning_list": "",
        "success": "20",
        "success_list": "6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25"
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest solution would be to not use strict mode but your code is a mess you need to do some code refactoring. For example it's bad idea to declare functions in for loop.

Comment: Almis: I hope you don't mind showing me how to improve. I would like to learn, and not make this mistake again.

Comment: @Almis The **correct** solution would be to always use strict mode and fix the errors instead.

Comment: @Nit: Can you please give me hints - if you think of any ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nit I agree this why I said the easiest solution :) but I dont suggest it too

Comment: Declare your functions outside the loop, then call them from within the loop.  As it is you are redefining the function every time the loop iterates, which is exactly what the error message you got is warning you not to do.

Comment: @开发人员 I think this is the source of your problem, if you take functions out of for loop everything will work fine

Comment: @Almis: Will try to do that. Thanks for your suggestions. :D

Comment: @DanielBeck : Can you please teach me how to do it ?

Comment: @开发人员 Remove the functions which are inside the `for..in` loop, and put them outside the `for..in` loop (preferably outside the `$.ajax` closure as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.`

Either delete line 1 (`'use strict';`) or define `updateInfo(x)` outside the loop (better in the top scope, like on line 4).

This is the function: you have to call it with the 3 parameters as you use those objects in it.

I won't write you the code you need, as I think it's up to you. I can give you hints on what you have to do:

1. get the list of variables you use in the function
2. make them arguments if they change, while the others may be used using a higher or equal scope (i.e. define the variables first and then the function)

Comment: Can you please show me, how would I move my updateInfo() function out of my for-loop ?

Comment: I won't write the function for you. I'm not here to write your code. If you have familiarity with any programming language, just keep in mind you can use variables in the scope (like you did) and variables from arguments. Make them arguments if they're out of scope, use them directly if you've defined them in a higher or in the same scope.

Comment: I did it. Thanks though.